# value inside switch wont change, unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, switch-statement

i have switch and some case. this code only work on first line. it need to reload twice so the rest of the code would work. it change enemy damage at first but it need to reload twice to change killScore. anyone know why?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;


public class Difficulty : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int difficulty;
    public ammo enemyDamage;
    public enemy enemy1;
    public enemy enemy2;
    //public enemy enemy2;
    public TextMeshProUGUI diff;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        difficulty = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Difficulty");
        diff.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Difficulty").ToString();
    
        switch(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Difficulty"))
        {
            case 0:
                difficulties(3,100);
                break;
            case 1:
                difficulties(5,200);
                break;
            case 2:
                difficulties(7,300);
                break;
        }
        
        Debug.Log("kill score : " + enemy1.killScore);
        Debug.Log("difficulty : " + difficulty);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }

    void difficulties(int a, int b)
    {
        enemyDamage.enemyDamage = a;
        enemy1.killScore = b;
        enemy2.killScore = b;
    }
}
```

it change value on the prefab but the prefab i put on the scene doesnt.

Comment: Maybe because you log the kill score before you assign the values?

Comment: after i take out the log, the problem is still there.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? And you shouldn't take out the log but love it after the switch when the values are already assigned

Comment: oh im sorry sir, my mistake to put the log at first. but after i put the log in the last part of awake, the log change. prefab on the project tab which I add script the value itself  is changing, but the other prefab which I put in the scene doesn't change at all  when I change the case .

 It needs to have 2nd reload to change the value in the prefab in the scene.

Comment: If you change the value on a **prefab** (meaning an Asset in the ProjectView) then it won't have any effect on an instance that is living in the current Scene .. are you sure you are referencing the correct objects ?

Comment: yes i make sure a thousand time its correct. but i find another sollution for this. i put kill score on PlayerPrefs and load it direct on enemy script. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i change the script and put killScore on PlayerPref and it will change in the main menu before play scene. thank you